# Implement Pagination in Lightning Component by standard functionality

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to implement pagination on lightning componet. Is there any standard functionality present in salesforce? The pagination should be as displayed in image.

[image]

Basically, need an ability to jump to any page, end, beginning, next, previous, and knowing approximately how many pages.

Comment: Either you can use the base component [`Button Group`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonGroup/example) or [`SLDS markup`](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/button-groups/) for creating the layout you need and better control. There is no standard component which would satisfy your requirement, check for some implementation online or build you own, then come back with a specific question.

Comment: https://www.mstsolutions.com/technical/pagination-using-lightning-components/

Comment: http://sfdcfacts.com/lightning/lightning-pagination-with-page-number-navigation-using-client-side-controller/

Comment: https://github.com/amitastreait/Pagination-in-Lightning-Component